# Egoroff's theorem. Why does the set have to be closed?

Tags: measure-theory

Egoroff's theorem (or Yegorov's theorem) states that if we have a set of finite measure $E$ and a sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n\}$ defined on $E$ that converge pointwise on $E$ to a real-valued function $f$, then for each $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a closed set $F$ which is nearly the same size as $E$ (i.e. $m(E\setminus F) < \epsilon$ on which our sequence of measurable functions converges to $f$ uniformly.

My question is, why does the set on which this uniform convergence occurs have to be a closed set?  Why can't it be an open set?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, it just can be if you'd like.  The theorem isn't telling you that the only such sets $F$ are closed, just that there is a set that satisfies the convergence requirement and is also closed.